# Get singleton instance in another singleton constructor

Tags: java, constructor, static, initialization, singleton

Is there any problem to call a singleton instance in a singleton class's constructor?

I have a singleton A and in A's constructor, I call singleton B.getInstance().otherMethod(). And when I call A.getInstance() in other class, it gives me an 
"ExceptionInInitializerError" caused by "NullpointerException" with B.getInstance().otherMethod(). So what might be the problem?

Edit:

Singleton A

```
public class A{

   // SingletonHolder is a container class to hold singleton instance 
  private static final SingletonHolder<A> singletonA = new SingletonHodler<>(new A());

     private A(){

   // class B is also a singlton using SingletonHolder class
   Map map = B.getInstance().getMap();
  }
     public static A getInstance(){

  //.instance() is a method in SingletonHolder to return singleton instance
        return singletonA.instance();
    }
 }
```

When I call A.getInstance() in a test class. I get the exception mentioned above.

Comment: please include both singletons code

Comment: Is that a circular dependency in class initialisation? (Top tip: Don't use singletons.)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin It seems like when I call A instance = A.getInstance() in another class, B cannot be initialized.

Comment: @HenlenLee So you're trying to get an `A` which is creating a `B` which needs an `A` (or the other way around)? `B` can't get an `A` because the constructor of `A` hasn't returned yet. Avoiding the singletons, you could have the constructor for `A` pass `this` to the constructor of `B` (though note, `A` wont be full constructed yet). Alternatively add a `setA` method (or similar) onto `B`.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline So why it works when I change singleton B to another class which is not a singleton?

Comment: @HenlenLee Presumably you then don't have circular references.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline Thank you very much.